# After hexo d, when diaplay Copying files from public folder... git stopped, i don't know why

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, github-pages, hexo

```
hexo d
INFO  Validating config
INFO  Deploying: git
INFO  Clearing .deploy_git folder...
INFO  Copying files from public folder...
```

STOPPED！！！

_config.yml have blank

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repository: https://github.com/h****t/h****t.github.io
  branch: main
```

hexo clean

```
$ hexo clean
INFO  Validating config
INFO  Deleted database.
INFO  Deleted public folder.
```

hexo g

```
$ hexo g
INFO  Validating config
INFO  Start processing
INFO  Files loaded in 821 ms
(node:1032) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1032) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1032) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1032) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1032) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1032) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
INFO  Generated: archives/index.html
INFO  Generated: archives/2021/index.html
INFO  Generated: archives/2021/02/index.html
INFO  Generated: index.html
INFO  Generated: fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css
INFO  Generated: js/script.js
INFO  Generated: css/style.css
INFO  Generated: 2021/02/07/hello-world/index.html
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/FontAwesome.otf
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
INFO  Generated: fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.js
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
INFO  Generated: js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
INFO  Generated: css/images/banner.jpg
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
INFO  17 files generated in 1.98 s
```

hexo s

```
$ hexo s
INFO  Validating config
INFO  Start processing
INFO  Hexo is running at http://localhost:4000 . Press Ctrl+C to stop.
```

hexo d

```
$ hexo d
INFO  Validating config
INFO  Deploying: git
INFO  Clearing .deploy_git folder...
INFO  Copying files from public folder...
```

it stopped at `INFO  Copying files from public folder...`
i think my`_config.yml`is right, because i deploy another Github account and it succeed, but i dont know why this account failed, SSH is connected:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi h****t! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Please Help me!!!，Thanks very much！！！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run :

```
npm un hexo-deployer-git
npm i hexojs/hexo-deployer-git
```

https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/4634

The test is effective

Comment: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-deployer-git/pull/198